# What is wrong with this common lisp code?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Basically I tried evaluating the function below but keep getting the following error:

```
 WARNING :
MAINDIA is neither declared nor bound,
it will be treated as if it were declared SPECIAL.
WARNING :
SOUT is neither declared nor bound,
it will be treated as if it were declared SPECIAL.
WARNING :
NORT is neither declared nor bound,
it will be treated as if it were declared SPECIAL.
*** - NIL: variable MAINDIA has no value
The following restarts are available:
ABORT          :R1      Abort debug loop
ABORT          :R2      Abort debug loop
ABORT          :R3      Abort debug loop
ABORT          :R4      Abort debug loop
ABORT          :R5      Abort debug loop
ABORT          :R6      Abort debug loop
ABORT          :R7      Abort debug loop
ABORT          :R8      Abort main loop
```

When I tried copy and paste an example from the internet it works, but when I manually type it into the interpreter it doesn't work. Also, I am running CLISP from emacs.

Code:

```
(defun diagonal-mast (sq)
  (let* ((maindia #x8040201008040201)
         (diag (- (* 8 (logand sq 7))
                  (logand sq 56)))
         (nort (logand (- diag)
                       (ash diag -31)))
         (sout (logand diag (ash (- diag) -31))))
    (ash (ash maindia (- sout))
         nort)))
```

**NOte: I am on CLISP 2.48**

Comment: Try `let`, rather than `let*` - you are not using the definitions in each other.

Comment: @Marcin you're wrong, he's indeed using them. Anyway, this code is perfectly valid and works well in SBCL. Check what's the value of `let*` (could it be, that you've redefined it somewhere?)

Comment: @VsevolodDyomkin: Only `diag`, but yes - it should be valid, which is why I suggested trying let.

Comment: Works perfectly fine in my CLISP 2.48...

Comment: no errors returned in sbcl 1.0.55.

Comment: @Marcin: for some reason when I copied and pasted an example from the Internet it works, but when I manually type it into the interpreter, it doesn't work; I am running clisp on my emacs btw.

Comment: @Mark: I suggest you expand on that quirk in the body of the question.

Comment: Works fine in both CLISP 2.49 and SBCL 1.0.53 here.  If it works when you copy-and-paste but not when you type it in, then (assuming you're not making any typos) it sounds like a terminal/emacs problem, not a code problem.  Are you using SLIME?

Comment: I suspect that you simply mistyped.  For example, if you added one more parenthesis after `-31`, it could explain the errors.

Comment: @Svante: I have not mistyped, I copied the example straight from my editor.

Comment: Mark, I think your copy and paste procedure is adding some unprintable characters. Please try configuring SLIME for Clisp and evaluating it from a slime buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all likelihood, your problem is with emacs, not with the code, because it's running fine in the commenters' and my lisps.  I'm not on emacs anymore, so it's possible the following solution is deprecated or entirely false, but if you start Emacs via emacs --debug-init and get an error message, you've got some setup issue rather than a code issue. Elsewise, it seems like your lisp implementation is the problem, not your lisp writing. If it's somehow your lisp implementation, just rebuild and it should be fine. If it's your setup, i'm pretty sure [slimedev](http://common-lisp.net/project/slime/#bug-tracker) has some a pretty exhaustive list of bugs and fixes. Good hunting.